# Does Twitter let you preview links before posting on web?

Tags: twitter

I'm having a discussion in my company regarding some Twitter posting related issues. One thing emerged: my colleagues claim that Twitter at some point was able to show a link preview before posting on the Twitter website. That would mean something like: you paste a link into the tweeting field and **before posting** you get a card/image appearing near the field — the same way it happens in at least the current version of iOS Twitter app.

Could this really be the case? I tested now and it seems now Twitter does not preview any link — you just paste it, post it, and after a page refresh a card appears below the link in your tweet.

However I cannot find any trace of this feature ever existing on web.

Comment: I can rearticulate the question to refer to present time. Because essentially it's about whether Twitter has this feature now.

Comment: I don't recall it ever doing that. Admittedly, I am far from a Twitter power user. Could they be conflating it with, say, Facebook?

Comment: no, seems they are not.

Comment: Are they, perhaps, thinking of [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview)? They're not universal, however. The target site needs to add some markup to their HTML to get them to work.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Still, many sites with Twitter cards enabled in their code that I tested don't show this preview before posting in the web interface of Twitter. Such as Mashable: http://mashable.com/2017/04/27/hodor-white-walker-game-of-thrones-season-7-spoilers